# Generate new random number every 5 seconds PHP

Tags: php, random, self-updating

I need to update a variable number $x with a new random value every 5 seconds (length not really important). I know how to do it with a finite loop, however if I want it to be continuous and always just update. I know how to do it with just updating the header, but since I dont want the entire page to reload that is not really an option. Below Ive tried to trick it with a infinite loop (not the best way), but what I am also seeing running this is that it gives me the same number over and over.

Any ideas?

```
    <?php

echo "Random Number Updating <br>";
$n = 5;
$x = rand(1,10);

function random() {
    $interval = 5; // Interval in seconds
    srand(floor(time() / $interval)); 
    $x = rand(0, 10); 
    echo "$x";
}

while ($x <= 6){
 random();   
}


?>
```

Comment: is this a CLI script?

Comment: no, just stand alone. im testing a few things, and need something that spits out a random number ever 5 secs (or so)...

Comment: There is nothing in your code that waits 5 or any number of seconds. So you are seeding the same number and getting the same results.

Comment: @jeroen could you please give me a suggestion as how to fix this then?

Comment: I think you can do the same using session and ajax.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In PHP(with refresh):

```
while(true) {
    if( time() % 5 == 0 ) { // get time in seconds and check if it is multiple of 5
        echo rand(0, 10);
        break; // break the loop
    } else {
        sleep(1);
    }
}
header("Refresh:5"); // refresh after 5 seconds
```

In JS(without refresh):

```
<div id="update">--</div>
<script>
    var update = document.getElementById("update");
    setInterval(() => update.innerHTML = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10), 5000);
    // 5 * 1000 ms = 5 seconds   ----------------------------------------^^^^
</script>
```

Comment: wouldn't `while(true) {` create an infinite loop?

Comment: @AkintundeOlawale Try running it and wait for 5 seconds :)

Comment: true ;) haven't had coffee yet @AniketSahrawat

Comment: PHP MUST DIE - Request > PHP > Response > Die. It's not designed for long running scripts. Especially on a webserver, which will eventaually time out despite you changing PHP settings. This is the best solution if you insist on using PHP for this task. Hence I'm voting this answer up, and I hope this is the solution you actually use.

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php

function display_random_numbers($limit, $interval)
{
    $counter = 1;
    while($counter++ <= $limit) {
        $number = rand(1, 10);
        echo $number . "\n";
        sleep($interval);
    }
}

display_random_numbers(10, 1);
```

Example output:

```
1
2
10
9
8
9
9
8
4
6
```